CKEditor5 v43 - Add custom plugin code while using the CDN for CKEditor5
In our project we want to use the CDN for ckeditor5, and we also need to add custom plugins.
As per this link "https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/releases/tag/v42.0.0", under "Release Highlights", this line is mentioned:
"All the new distribution methods (available via npm, CDN, and ZIP downloads) allow dynamic plugin registration making it easy to add or remove plugins dynamically."
Could you please help with an example on how to use CDN as the source, and register custom developed plugins to it?
